# How to simulate touch event?

Tags: iphone, events, touch, multi-touch

I want to be able to invoke touch events without user interactions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could manually call touches begin and touches end.

I think there may be a better solution to whatever you are trying to do,  This seems like a very unconventional thing to do.

Comment: No, you can't because according to the link that @Zydeco posted, "The iPhone lacks specific methods to create UIEvent and UITouch objects."

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `UIResponder's touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:`

Comment: You can't call those methods because according to the link that @Zydeco posted, "The iPhone lacks specific methods to create UIEvent and UITouch objects."