# Simulate a tap, is possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know that is possible to intercept a tap on a screen, but I want to know if is it possible to simulate a tap in a point of screen (with x and y coordinates).
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate touch event ？](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992299/how-to-simulate-touch-event)

Answer (score 3):

```
UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] initInView:view];
UIEvent *eventDown = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];

[touch.view touchesBegan:[eventDown allTouches] withEvent:eventDown];

[touch setPhase:UITouchPhaseEnded];
UIEvent *eventUp = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];

[touch.view touchesEnded:[eventUp allTouches] withEvent:eventUp];

[eventDown release];
[eventUp release];
[touch release];
```

from here
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html

Comment: downvote because - this technique is out of context and requires more code (at the link) that uses private API's.

Comment: upvote because - synthesizing a touch in general is going to require accessing some sort of private API.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a non-jailbroken device, check this: [PTFakeTouch](https://github.com/Ret70/PTFakeTouch) (worked for ios 11). It only works inside your applications. Since you are using private APIs, you might get rejected from the App Store.

**If you want to simulate system-wide touch events, you have to jailbreak your device.**

**Check these links for jailbroken devices:**

**[Simulate Touch Event on iOS - jailbroken - iOS13+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025335/simulate-touch-event-on-ios-jailbroken-ios13/)**

**[Is possible to simulate touch event using an external keyboard on ios jailbroken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237164/is-possible-to-simulate-touch-event-using-an-external-keyboard-on-ios-jailbroken/63026222#63026222)**