# Simulate Touch Event on iOS - jailbroken - iOS13+

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, tweak, event-simulation

Are there any tweaks that can simulate touch event on iPhone without injecting into processes? I am looking for a tweak that can be used to simulate event at system level.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to make a macro? automatic screen touch?